How to Structure Project
Just learning .NET and compared to other stacks, the project structure is very confusing to me.
I am doing Advent of Code and I would like to have separate folders for each day, e.g. Day 1, Day 2.. and each folder would have its own Solution.cs.
But when I try to run it, I can only run Day 1 solution.
I would just like to run each Day on its own, for example like with python python3 day1.py - that simple.
Can someone explain how .NET Project structure works and how can I set it up.

You need a single entry point. That can call whatever method you want. If you want separate entry points either handle it by command line arguments or you’ll have to create separate projects for each, which usually isn’t fun.
Or you can install dotnet-script tool which can run C# code files separately

A project usually compiles to a single exe (or dll). You run the exe, which doesn't know about separate "cs files"

In .NET one project results in one assembly (*.exe or *.dll). You always create a Solution which contains at least one Project. You can then add more projects to the same solution. In Visual Studio (or any other IDE) you should then always open the solution (the *.sln file), not single projects (*.csproj) or single files (*.cs).
These projects within the solution could be named Day1, Day2, Day3, etc.
You can then select the desired startup project in the IDE.
This is a bit more involved than the next solution I will present, but has the advantage that you can create projects of different types like Console applications, Windows Forms applications or Web pages and many more and to use different frameworks and settings. But you can also combine both approaches (this is what I do to elaborate and test my stackoverflow answers).

Another approach is to create one class per day in the same project. You then need a way to switch between these days.
Assuming the following static classes (each one in its own file):
// Day1.cs
internal static class Day1
{
    public static void Execute()
    {
        // your daily code goes here...
    }
}

// Day2.cs
internal static class Day2
{
    public static void Execute()
    {
        // your daily code goes here...
    }
}

// ... and so on

Then in Program.cs you would have this code to run the day 1 code:
Day1.Execute();

It is then easy to switch to another "application" by simply editing the day number.
You can also add folders to the project. This allows you to  group files belonging to the same "day" together. These files will also automatically get their own namespace reflecting the folder name. This is helpful in cases where you have classes with the same name and avoids name clashes.
